What is ToParquetBarrier in Dask Dataframe
I'm trying to code some heavy data merging tool and I would like to handle more data than fits into my ram at the same time.
It seems like the to_parquet function has a function called "ToParquetBarrier" which force all nodes to be present. What does this call do and how can I avoid this?

the single right node is "toparquetbarrier", the column next to it "lambda-fused-toparquetdata"
the respective function is
dataFrame.to_parquet(destinationFolder, write_metadata_file=True, overwrite=True)

and dataFrame.known_divisions is True
